# SQL query error :Incorrect Syntax Near "#"?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, datetime

When I try to execute this SQL query:

```
savInto.CommandText = "update onCommands set warnDate =#" & movDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") 
& "#,updateDate =#" & Date.Now.ToShortDateString 
& "#,transportCompany ='" & Trim(Company.Text) 
& "' where ID =" & moveID
```

I get this error:

```
Incorrect syntax near '#'
```

Comment: Can we see the actual sql? (after all the parsing to strings)

Comment: Try using single quotes around `MM/dd/yyyy`

Comment: Use sql-parameters instead of string concatenation if you build a sql query. Otherwise you are open for [**sql-injection**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx) and localization issues.

Comment: Print out your entire string to a log so that you can see exactly what is being executed. This may give you a clue as to the syntax error

Comment: Thank you a lot, my problem was solved by the first answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the main problem is that you're trying to provide the parameter as part of the SQL itself. While there *are* ways of doing that (use an apostrophe rather than `#`), it's generally a bad idea:

- It invites [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) when used with arbitrary strings
- It makes it harder to read the code
- It introduces unnecessary string conversions

Instead, you should use parameterized SQL and specify the value for the parameter. Something like:

```
savInto.CommandText = "update onCommands set warnDate = @warnDate" & 
    ", updateDate = @updateDate, transportCompany = @transportCompany" &
    " where ID=@moveID"
savInto.Parameters.Add("@warnDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = movDate
savInto.Parameters.Add("@updateDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Date.Now
savInto.Parameters.Add("@transportCompany", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Trim(Company.Text)
savInto.Parameters.Add("@moveID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = moveID
```

Comment: Additionally, the `#date#` syntax, isn't that Access / JET?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I believe that's from Access indeed.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Possibly. I'm not going to dwell on that, given that it's a fundamentally bad approach :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Well it's not a literal when it's getting the value from a variable...

Comment: thank you a lot, that was the best solution,anyway, even if my way is unsafe and bad,but what is the error ? i tried to change the # to ' and error still.

Comment: @AymAnAbuOmar: Maybe the SQL date literal is expected to be in a different format, e.g. yyyy-MM-dd. I don't know, and you shouldn't need to care, because you're not really trying to perform a string conversion: you're trying to provide a date to the database. That's the beauty of using parameterized SQL.

Comment: Thank you very much mr Jon, your answer was very helpfully

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using # character? What database are you using (sql server, oracle, mysql...)

Try this:

```
savInto.CommandText = "update onCommands set warnDate ='" & movDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "',updateDate ='" & Date.Now.ToShortDateString & "',transportCompany ='" & Trim(Company.Text) & "' where ID =" & moveID
```

Comment: While your answer is technically correct, it's not a good approach in general.