# i got the error in the query that " incorrect syntax error near '#' how to solve it

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

i got the error in the query that " incorrect syntax error near '#' how to solve it

Code:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT 
                    (invoiceNo) as [Invoice No],
                    (InvoiceDate) as [Invoice Date],
                    (Sales.CustomerID) as [Customer ID],
                    (CustomerName) as [Customer Name],
                    (GrandTotal) as [Grand Total],
                    (TotalPayment) as [Total Payment],
                    (PaymentDue) as [Payment Due] 
                    from Sales,Customer 
                        where 
                           Sales.CustomerID=Customer.CustomerID 
                        and 
                           InvoiceDate between #" + DateTimePicker2.Text + "# And #" + DateTimePicker1.Text + "# and PaymentDue > 0 
                        order by 
                           InvoiceDate desc", con);
```

Comment: Formatting? Where is the question? WHat have you tried?

Comment: i got the error in the query that " incorrect syntax error near '#' how to solve it

Comment: Which DBMS do you use? I thin your `#` mist be `'`.

Comment: `#` is for JET not T-SQL. Just use parameters and save yourself having to concatenate strings and leave yourself wide open to SQL injection. This isn't PHP.

Comment: so wat will be that changes in this query

Comment: **SQL** is a *query language*. It is **not** the name of a database product. Every relational database (Oracle, Postgres, DB2, Firebird, Microsoft SQL Server,...) is a "SQL database"

Comment: ohh yeah MS-SQL Server

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sql query error :Incorrect Syntax Near "#"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287032/sql-query-error-incorrect-syntax-near)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I like that you didn't name MySQL as a relational database.

Answer (score 3):

If you using `TSQL`, I think you should pass `date` as string. However, I'm not sure do you need any time portion, you may need to modify the format in `tostring`

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT 
                    (invoiceNo) as [Invoice No],
                    (InvoiceDate) as [Invoice Date],
                    (Sales.CustomerID) as [Customer ID],
                    (CustomerName) as [Customer Name],
                    (GrandTotal) as [Grand Total],
                    (TotalPayment) as [Total Payment],
                    (PaymentDue) as [Payment Due] 
                    from Sales,Customer 
                        where 
                           Sales.CustomerID=Customer.CustomerID 
                        and 
                           InvoiceDate between '" + DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "' 
                        And '" + DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "' and PaymentDue > 0 
                        order by 
                           InvoiceDate desc", con);
```